# Js: loop through array indefinetly

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

Short story I want to change an image every 4 seconds from an array of images. What do I need to add here to make this happen.

```
var list = ["img1", "img2", "img3"];

function ChangeBackground () {
  document.getElementById('background').src = "images/"+list[i];
}

window.setInterval(ChangeBackground(), 4000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a closure over the index.

```js
function changeBackground() {
    var i = 0,
        imgURL = 'http://lorempixel.com/250/200/abstract/';
    return function () {
        document.getElementById('background').src = imgURL + list[i++];
        i %= list.length; // prevent looping over the length
    };
}

var list = [3, 1, 4, 7];

setInterval(changeBackground(), 4000);
//                          ^^         with brackets for returning function
```

```html
<img id="background">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var list = ["img1", "img2", "img3"];
var i=0;
function ChangeBackground () {
   i++;
   if(i>list.length-1){
       i=0;
   }
   document.getElementById('background').src = "images/"+list[i];
}

window.setInterval(ChangeBackground(), 4000);
```

Note that this does pollute the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ["img1", "img2", "img3"],
    i = 0;                                                            // declare and initialize i outside of the function

function ChangeBackground () {
    document.getElementById('background').src = "images/" + list[i];
    i = (i + 1) % list.length;                                        // increment i after each call to this function (make sure i come back to 0 if it exceeds the length of the array using the modulo % operator)
}

window.setInterval(ChangeBackground, 4000);                           // pass a reference to the function not its return value (notice there is no parens after the function name)
```

Comment: Thank you! This answered everything I wanted to know ^^